# Can I run greasemonkey in terminal?

Tags: terminal, virtual-machine, greasemonkey

I am new to Greasemonkey, and I think it is a extension in firefox. But is there a way I can use it in terminal(virtual machine environment) ? I can install firefox in my virtual machine. But how can I run it?